# Duplicating actor in Unity

Tags: unity

New to video game development and im working in unity on a Mac right now. I also have been using unreal on my pc figuring them both out. Im trying to (in unity) quickly copy prefabs by dragging them to different spots on mac? Basically the unreal engine equivalent to Alt + dragging your actor on windows. I've tried looking it up and shortcuts dont help and randomly pressing buttons and dragging is getting me nowhere fast[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+D (or Command-D on OSX) duplicates the selected objects/assets in-place.

You can then move the copies to a new location.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't want to work. I'll try it again. Also I have a 200x200 scale lanscape that just like compressed and went blue. I turned off the fog and that took care of the blue but it is still compressed. I'll try and get an image

Comment: Got the duplicate working. Im and idiot and was doing control. Im not an apple guy lol

Comment: Figured that out too. Apparently I accidentally clicked on 2D